# php validate phone number

Tags: php, forms, validation

I need help with form validation. Specifically for Australian phone numbers. I can only do basic validation using the preg_match() method but I'm stuck with this.

Must start with +614, (04) or 04; then any grouping of 8 more digits
and single spaces is permitted.

That's the validation criteria, any help is appreciated.

```
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$name)) {
        $numberErr = "Number format is invalid"
    }
```

that's all I can do I don't know how to add conditions for the start of the number (start with +614, (04) or 04.

Edit: Also need help with credit card validation, validation criteria is:
Any grouping of 12 - 19 numbers and single spaces are permitted.

```
if(!preg_match('/[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/', $card)) {
        $cardErr = "Invalid card number";
    }
```

I can't find anything that teaches preg_match() method parameters so I honestly don't even know what the above code is doing.
Sorry for my noobness ;)

Comment: Let's see your preg_match attempt.  Your question needs more details.  Did you have a look at the tens of similar questions on this site before asking?  I prefer not to answer questions without a coding attempt because it can lead to volunteer abuse in this community/network.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: @Adnan we are happy to help you fix your broken code.  Show us some broken code please.

Comment: I know what Aussie phone numbers look like, but when you say "any grouping of 8 more digits" <- that is not a clear description of the logic that you need.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think it means the maximum number of digits shouldn't exceed 12 including (+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using anchors (`^` and `$`) so that the start and the end of the string are identified.  The leading characters are in the first non-capturing group with pipes that represent "OR".  The second non-capturing group, contains the "space-tolerant" 8-digit substring.

Let me know if you have any fringe cases that are not handled properly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uHOVM))

```
$aussie_mobiles = ['+614 1234 5678', '02 11112222', '(04)98765432', '0413572468', '+614 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'];

foreach ($aussie_mobiles as $mob) {
    echo "$mob: ";
    if (preg_match('~^(?:\+614|\(04\)|04)(?: *\d){8}$~', $mob)) {
        echo "pass\n";
    } else {
        echo "fail\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
+614 1234 5678: pass
02 11112222: fail
(04)98765432: pass
0413572468: pass
+614 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8: pass
```